# "Implicitly denied" when I've explicitly allowed S3 IAM user actions in AWS Policy Simulator

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I am trying to simulate an IAM policy I want to attach to a user so I can restrict their access to two buckets, one for file upload and one for file download.

The policy simulator tells me that the following policy does not work and I cannot figure out why, but it seems to be to do with the wildcards.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "GetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket-*-report-output/*.csv"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "PutObjects",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket-*-report-input/*.csv"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The policy simulator says the following policy does work however:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "GetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket-*-report-output"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "PutObjects",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket-*-report-input"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

There must be something I am missing about how to structure the policy, but I want to restrict access to the buckets in the policy, for the operations mentioned, but I also want to ensure that the user can only add and retrieve files with `.csv` extension.

Below is a screenshot of the simulator:

[image]

Comment: Have you actually tried the policy? What does the policy simulator exactly say?

Comment: Policy simulator says top one doesnt work and bottom one does, which I dont understand. 

I do not have permission to actually create IAM users in my account so I need to write this policy as text and attach it to a ticket for another team to complete which is why I wanted to use the simulator to try out the policy first.

Comment: If you want to know exactly it says "denied   Implicitly denied (no matching statements)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your policy is 100% correct - the IAM Policy Simulator is showing wrong results for some absurd reason.**

I also can reproduce your problem using the above policy, and the results are all over the place - sometimes both allowed, both denied, only one allowed etc.

It seems to be having an issue with the double wildcard, and sometimes it is coming back with the wrong resource ARN being evaluated in the HTTP response being returned (I'm sometimes seeing both ARNs set to `output` instead of only 1 set to `output` in the network tab for the HTTP response - caching?).

It's not limited to `PutObject` either only and it's giving me loads of conflicting results with the double wildcard, even for other actions like `s3:RestoreObject`.

Regardless, I'm not sure what the issue is but your policy is correct - ignore IAM Policy Simulator in this case.

If you have access to AWS Support, I would create a support ticket there or post this same question as a potential bug on the [AWS forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=76&start=0).

---

Evidence of a conflicting result, even though I have exactly recreated your scenario:

[image]

Comment: I just had the same experience while testing the above policies in the IAM Policy Simulator.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, I thought maybe I misunderstood the guidance on wildcards, I get they cannot span sections but the documentation seems to imply there isnt a restriction on them within a section.

I also noted some odd behaviour where when testing a policy earlier was all flagged as wrong, I then refreshed and pasted the same policy in and it worked..

Comment: It can be flaky at times & it seems that it's not liking something - AWS support will probably confirm that and I'll raise with someone on the IAM team next time I create a support ticket with them :)